# OS Places API returns the house but not flats in that house

Tags: united-kingdom

For example, following request returns the buildings (houses) but not flats in those buildings. Looking up same data in EPC register will return all individual flats.

Are flats not supported in OS Data Hub?

*https://api.os.uk/search/places/v1/postcode?postcode=RG302DE&key=xxx*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.